# How should I remove data from array?

Tags: php

**Question**

Basically I want to send reminder emails to the people who haven't accepted the challenge yet. From **challenges** table I get the emails who have been challenged and then from **a_challenges** table I get the emails (usernames) who have accepted the challenge.

**Problem**

I want to basically remove the email addresses which are in the **a_challenges** table from the array coming from **challenges** table as those people have already accepted the challenge so i don't want to send them an reminder email. Any help will be appreciated.

**Code**

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/dbConnector.php');
    $dbCon = new dbConnector();//define the DB connection
    $query_challenges = "Select distinct * from challenges";//query to fetch records from challenges table like usernames who have been challenged
    //echo $query_challenges;
    $result_challenges = $dbCon->query($query_challenges);//execute query


    //start while loop to fetch the records
    while($row_tr = $dbCon->fetchArray($result_challenges)){
        $t_name = $row_tr['t_name'];
        $c_emails = $row_tr['c_emails'];
        echo "<br /><br />".$t_name."<br /><br />";

            $query_a_challenges = "Select * from a_challenges where t_name='".$t_name."'";//query to fetch records from a_challenges table like usernames who have accepted the challenge, etc
            //echo $query_a_challenges;
            $result_a_challenges = $dbCon->query($query_a_challenges);//execute query
            while($row_a_challenges = $dbCon->fetchArray($result_a_challenges)){
                echo "Accepted==> ". $row_a_challenges['full_name']." -- ";
                echo $row_a_challenges['username']."<br /><br />";
            }//end while a_challenges..

        //echo $c_emails."<br /><br />";
        $c_emails = explode(',', $c_emails);
        for($i=0; $i<count($c_emails); $i++){
            echo $c_emails[$i]."<br />";
        }//end for
    }//end while challenges..
?>
```

**Actual Output**

```
Team==> AGS Larger Lads

Accepted==> Donald -- donald@example.com

Accepted==> David -- david@example.com

Accepted==> Sean -- Sean@example.com
```

***Send email to below mentioned address:***

```
byrne@example.com
neil@example.com
brendan@example.com
Sean@example.com
donald@example.com
saunders@example.com
david@example.com
```

**Expected Output**

```
Team==> AGS Larger Lads

Accepted==> Donald -- donald@example.com

Accepted==> David -- david@example.com

Accepted==> Sean -- Sean@example.com
```

***Send email to below mentioned address:***

```
byrne@example.com
neil@example.com
brendan@example.com
saunders@example.com
```

Comment: what's the difference between the expected and the actual output?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE address NOT IN (SELECT address FROM teams)` ...or something along those lines. Let the database do it!

Comment: Instead of doing this all in PHP you can do that in your mysql query as well. and i think this will be easy .

Comment: Why don't you just select those addresses only, to which a reminder message wasn't sent?

Comment: can you post the schema?  it is very hard to give a correct solution.

Comment: @deceze I know but in team_request table I have multiple addresses in same field separated by ",".

Comment: @colourtheweb And *that* is why you *normalize* your database and do not store several values in the same field! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest would be, to not remove the email address from the string, before you explode it it into the array (btw terrible way of storing email addresses in databases)

anyway, i just assumed that $row_teams['username'] is the email address
here is i think the most simplest way to do it with your code:

```
    while($row_tr = $dbCon->fetchArray($result_team_request)){
        $t_name = $row_tr['t_name'];
        $c_emails = $row_tr['c_emails'];
        echo "<br /><br />".$t_name."<br /><br />";


            $query_teams = "Select * from teams where t_name='".$t_name."'";//query to fetch records from teams table like usernames who have accepted the challenge, etc
            //echo $query_teams;
            $result_teams = $dbCon->query($query_teams);//execute query
            while($row_teams = $dbCon->fetchArray($result_teams)){
                echo "Accepted==> ". $row_teams['full_name']." -- ";
                echo $row_teams['username']."<br /><br />";

                //my new code line:
            $c_emails = str_replace($row_teams['username'],'',$c_emails);
            }//end while teams..
            $c_emails = explode(',', $c_emails); 

        //echo $c_emails."<br /><br />";

        for($i=0; $i<count($c_emails); $i++){
            echo $c_emails[$i]."<br />";
        }//end for
    }//end while team_request..
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to solve this in PHP, you want to restrict these results in the query from the database.    Essentially the code should be this:

```
select request.*, team.*  
from teams team, team_request request  
where team.name=request.team_name  
and request.accepted = false
```

This is of course speculation until you can post the full schema.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the `username` field contains the E-Mail, so you could simply

```
//start while loop to fetch the records
//*** NEW LINE HERE ***
$usedmails=array();
while($row_tr = $dbCon->fetchArray($result_team_request)){
    $t_name = $row_tr['t_name'];
    $c_emails = $row_tr['c_emails'];
    echo "<br /><br />".$t_name."<br /><br />";

        $query_teams = "Select * from teams where t_name='".$t_name."'";//query to fetch records from teams table like usernames who have accepted the challenge, etc
        //echo $query_teams;
        $result_teams = $dbCon->query($query_teams);//execute query
        while($row_teams = $dbCon->fetchArray($result_teams)){
            echo "Accepted==> ". $row_teams['full_name']." -- ";
            echo $row_teams['username']."<br /><br />";
            //*** NEW LINE HERE ***
            $usedmails[]=$row_teams['username'];
        }//end while teams..

    //echo $c_emails."<br /><br />";
    $c_emails = explode(',', $c_emails);
    // *** NEW LINE HERE ***
    $c_emails=array_diff($c_emails,$usedmails);
    for($i=0; $i<count($c_emails); $i++){
        echo $c_emails[$i]."<br />";
    }//end for
```

Comment: It's working for me but am getting this error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/vhosts/disciplinexgames.com/httpdocs/dx_scores/emails.php on line 31 "